# Flatpak support not enabled

Tags: appcenter, flatpak, sideload

After enabling flatpak by default (as proclaimed by the elementary team) my AppCentre still does not recognize flatpak apps as it should.

Do I need to do something here, or is it a bug?

---

Can I know one example, where I could see this dropdown enabling menu? I don't seem to be able to find one. Even the flatpaks I had installed before this don't appear in the installed category. Have I managed to break something here?

Comment: Same here, what I do is just using command line to install the flatpak applications, as described on the flatpak site.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure your system is up-to-date:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

After that, install the sideload package:

```
sudo apt install io.elementary.sideload
```

Now, you'll be able to open flatpack files with Sideload, and it will prompt you whether you want to install the app. In the AppCenter, apps that are available from multiple sources will have a dropdown enabling you to choose which one to install.

Comment: sideload Will be installed automatically later. But it's available in the repo for those who do not wish to wait. When it is installed, flatpaks can indeed be installed graphically.

Comment: unfortunately that thing does not work for me at all. it does nothing

Comment: @lecroix what happens if you right-click a flatpackref file -> Open with... -> Sideload?

Comment: that option works, but I have seen screenshots, where there's a dropdown menu in AppCentre. but apparently I am not the only one. another thing is now AppCenter always shows symstem updates available, even when everything's been updated

Comment: @lecroix To set Sideload as default, I suggest right-clicking on a flatpakref file -> Open with... -> Other application... -> Select Sideload -> check Set as default -> click Select. To see the elusive dropdown, open AppCenter and search for Notejot or VGrive (there are many, many other apps). For the system updates, there might be some ppas erroring out, so I run a `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y` in Terminal (look for errors and [remove the faulty ppas](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21108/in-app-centre-it-is-showing-failed-to-fetch-updates/21109#21109), if any)

Answer (score 1):

What I am doing is going to FlatHub (https://flathub.org/home), find the app I need, and install it. Like this,

[image]

Comment: Once the steps above are completed, the other flatpak apps from flathub.org will appear in appcenter.