# In app centre it is showing failed to fetch updates

Tags: updates, appcenter, ppa

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

Answer (score 2):

The tor-browser package in that ppa has not been updated in a very long time, I do not recommend using it. My suggestion is to remove that ppa, to get AppCenter working again, and then install tor from the ubuntu repository (as per the [Tor Project's instructions](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/debian)).

To remove the obsolete ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
```

After that, run `sudo apt update` to see if the error is gone. If all is well, try running `sudo apt upgrade` to bring your system up-to-date.

Comment: yaa it worked thanks

Comment: @Manikant Musunuru Excellent! Glad I could help. Now please upvote and accept the answer.